# Spring REST URI existence check

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, api

Let's assume a simple Spring based RESTful API with some nested Resources.

- A `User` is the root entity created by everyone to access the API
- Each `User` can create `Posts`, therefor a `Post` can't exist without a creator
- A `User` can also comment existing `Posts`, therefor a `Comment` belongs to a `Post`

For this API I picked the following RESTful routes:

- `/api/users` for `User`
- `/api/users/{userId}/posts` for `Post`
- `/api/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments` for `Comment`

About my question, should I validate that the parent resources exists? For example for the request `GET /api/users/2/posts/3/comments/7`, should I ensure that the entities `User(2)` and `Post(3)` also exists? Do I also have to make sure that the entities are related to each other and not any x arbitrary resources that exist are used?

**Example**

```
@PostMapping("/api/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments")
public void create(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @PathVariable("postId") Long postId, @RequestBody CommentPayload payload) {

    // userService.existsByIdWithPostId(userId, postId); ???

    commentService.createForPost(postId, payload);
}
```

To create the comment in the database, the `userId` is completely irrelevant, the `postId`is needed only. Should I still make sure that user with `userId` X exists and has a post with `postId` Y or should ignore it?

If yes how could I do this elegant? Because growing JPA/Repository queries like `Optional<Comment> findByUserIdAndPostIdAndId(...)` doesn't seem to be an solution... Should the validation then take place in several queries? The inclusion of all parents' ids complicates the actual query immense. In addition, the identifiers must be passed through all layers (service, security), which complicates the internal API.

Comment: @DumiduUdayanga They are url parameters, not query string.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Yes, you must check if the parent/root-entity exists and Yes you need to define relationship between entities

The Long answer:

The fact that a Post can not be created without a user, doesn't have to be checked by URL structure. The URL is just for clarifying **what resource is requested**. The check must be done directly in the code. Checking existence of a record does not need extra effort and methods, and that's because of the relationship between entities.

When you add a post for a user, using `/users/{userId}/posts` API, you need to add the post to the post-list of a user with `id=[userId]`, so you call the related repository method to fetch the user record (like `findById`), That itself is the act of checking the existence of user with `id=[userId]`. Cause if the repository returns null, you know user doesn't exist

For designing good, efficient and understandable API, follow this simple rule:

*If the resource can be accessed individually, it must have a basic URL as /[entity], else use the parent-child pattern (like what you have for posts).*

Note that this rule can not work all the time and many times you need to customize the API and change it to be more efficient.

So, If a user can see other users' posts, then you should design the API like:

- `/users` [requests for user entity]
- `/posts` [requests for post entity]

Then for request upon a specific user's posts, you should use `/users/{userId}/posts` for creating new post or reading them, and for request upon a specific post's comments you should use `/posts/{postId}/comments`.

As I understand the design of your app, you don't need `/comments` cause all comments are related to posts and should be accessed by the related post (like above). If comments can be accessed individually (like having a page that list all comments without caring about their related posts), then you need `/comments` API for more clarification

Comment: First yea comments can't be accessed individually. Second your example with posts and users is evident but what about one level deeper, what about comments related to my example?

Comment: @0x1C1B what do you mean by "comments related to my example"?

Comment: `/users/{userId}/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}` is this not allowed? If it is how to deal with it to validate the URI existence? Your example is evident just a once nested route isn't a problem... But what about n nested routes?

Comment: @0x1C1B Any URL you specify for your API is valid. Following the rule, since comments are not suppose to be accessed individually, then they should be accessed by their parents, which is `Post`. `User` is not parent of `Comment`, and since comment and post have relationship, checking existence of post record when adding new comment, has the same scenario of user-post relationship. So `/user/{userId} for the comments is unnecessary and redundant. In times when an entity has more than one parent or relationship, simply send parent/relation IDs in DTO, rather than in URL

Comment: What does it mean to my scenario? Should I've an additional route `/api/posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}` with omitted user prefix?

Comment: @0x1C1B Didn't say "your" scenario. I meant the scenario I stated in my answer for checking existence of a user record, when adding new posts. Yes, you should do that.

Comment: Yea sure but how should the comments route look like? Could you give me an route example for comments?

Comment: @0x1C1B you should set comments route, like you mentioned in tour previous comment: `/posts/{postId}/comments/..`

Comment: Okay this means posts are just accessible through `/api/users/{userId}/posts` and comments just through `/api/posts/{postId}/comments` right?

Comment: @0x1C1B for comments, yes, for posts, if posts can **not** be accessed individually, yes, else `/posts` is the main URL for post entity and `/users/{userId}/posts` is for posts of specific user